# Can there be a poset with 5 minimal elements, 1 maximal elemet and no greatest elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was trying to use an infinite chain and an isolated element and i get 1 maximal element, no greatest elements but I can't get 5 minimal elements. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use $\mathbb{N}$ plus 5 extra elements $a,b,c,d,e$. Use all the normal relations in $\mathbb{N}$, plus the following:
$$
\begin{align}
a &\le e \\
b &\le e \\
c &\le e \\
d &\le e
\end{align}
$$
Then we have

- Minimal elements: $1,a,b,c,d$ are the 5 minimal elements.
- Maximal elements: $e$ is the only maximal element.
- Greatest element: Nope, the "letter elements" vs elements of $\mathbb{N}$ are not comparable to each other, so there can't be a greatest element.